# java quick application

Tags: java

I want to create a database application using Java, currently I am using Netbeans and I am building everything from scratch, so I am reinventing the wheel.
Is there is any tools to use that help me to create a quick forms similar to Oracle forms?
I think Oracle ADF may be helpful but many articles and friends advised me to avoid using Jdeveloper. Does anyone have any idea what I should do to create Forms for users to input and query data for Desktop applications or Web applications quickly ?

Answer (score 0):

As it appears that you have not mastered Java, I would advise you to take the direct route of creating the UI, middleware code and Data access by hand coding.

You can use swing for desktop applications and webserver/servlet/HTML combo for creating web applications.

There is no shortcut you can take.

Comment: If all you want is something that works and don't care too much about having control over all details, there most certainly are shortcuts. It doesn't sound like the focus here is on learning, so coding everything by hand is hardly the best advice.

Comment: Thank you for you advises, i think i will contenue writing all code with my hande till using Spring Roo because i am making Desktop application, If there is a shortcut, what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) would be a good choice for rapidly developing a DB-backed web app in Java.